# Can I turn off PHP and HTML caching both within an Apache virtual host conf file?

Tags: apache2, cache, php7

I'm running a LAMP server on Ubuntu 16.04, typical LAMP setup. We have a family of websites running all controlled through virtual host files in the sites-available folder.

Pretty aggressive caching for the websites is handled through the global apache.conf file, and there is an opcache solution for php.

One website is experiencing some issues, but caching is preventing me from diagnosing it properly.

Preferably within the website.conf file, is it possible to configure Apache to ignore caching for only this website? I'd like to serve every request, and I'd like for PHP to be rebuilt from scratch on every request, too, (rather than be served from the opcode cache should there be a hit, and preferably without having to add a function like opcache_reset() to the top of every php page, or turn it off in the php.ini file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to configure apache to ignore *caching* in these various contexts:

1. server config - used in `httpd.conf`,
2. virtual host,
3. directory -  used inside `Directory, Location, Files, If, and Proxy` containers in the server configuration files,
4. .htaccess

In your case its *option 2* in this format `CacheDisable url-string | on`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    CacheDisable on    # OR
    CacheDisable "/foo_files"  # OR
    <Location "/foo">
        CacheDisable on
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Source:**

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cache.html#cachedisable

http://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/improve-website-performance-by-enabling-caching-in-apache/

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-apache-content-caching-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Where do I put this Virtual Host file?

Comment: Put it in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` then run `sudo a2ensite <name_of_conf_file>`!

Comment: I put it in `000_default.conf` and this happens: `apachectl[27596]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 30 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf: Invalid command 'CacheDisable', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Comment: Put it in it's own file!